# Aligning element to the page with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to mantain a circle centered to the page with media screen.
I'm using the css code "margin: 0 auto;" but, for some reason, it doesn't keep the circle in the center of the page.

CSS:

```
.dot {
height:550px;
width: 550px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 8%;
margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the full HTML and CSS you are using? This will help better understand your problem and how to assist you with solving it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try absolute centering.

```css
.dot {
  height:550px;
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border:2px solid;
  border-radius:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="dot"></div>
```